# Getting item price from Amazon python API

Tags: python, amazon-product-api

I am new to amzon api and I am trying to print the attributes of items returned from  the below code. .

```
    items = api.item_search('Books', Publisher="O'Reilly")
    for book in items:
        print book.ItemAttributes.Author, book.ItemAttributes.Title
```

This codes prints Author and Title of the books returned. But how can I get more details like the price of the book.

Comment: Are you trying to learn the api? Just do help(book.ItemAttributes). This will give you all the available methods.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- Have a look at the original [API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html). The options can be passed, in most cases, directly to `item_search` (see [wrapper docs](http://python-amazon-product-api.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.7/operations.html#amazonproduct.api.API.item_search) for details).
- Have a look at your XML element with `import lxml.etree; lxml.etree.tostring(book, pretty_print=True)`